# How can I fit all my figure's subfloats and caption on the same page?

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

I have a subfloat containing five pics (each of size 1040x463). I want them to fit on the same page. This is the tex I'm using but the the result is that the last pic is not appearing on the same page, so if anyone could please advise.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{animation1}\label{animation1}}
\qquad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{animation2}\label{animation2}}
\qquad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{animation3}\label{animation3}}
\qquad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{animation4}\label{animation4}}
\qquad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{animation5}\label{animation5}}
\caption {animation}
\label{animation}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Load the package `showframe` in order to visually see your limits. Then, you replace `width=\linewidth` by `height=xxx` where xxx is some distance in pt, mm, in, ex... and reduce this until all pictures fit on the page. The `[t]` is an unnecessary constraint here, as the `figure` will be set on its own page in every case.

Comment: BTW: it is not clear what the result should look like. What is the `\qquad` for? This is a horizontal distance. I would replace those by empty lines (setting the figures one below the other). And as you are reducing the width now, I would include `\centering` to your `figure`.

Comment: Why don't you use `p` instead of `t` as a floating specifier so to have the big figure in a page of floats?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi thanks for your comments! I replaced the `qquad` with `newline` but still the images don't fit in one page. The problem is that if I changed the height of the pics it will appear as if the image shrink and I don't want them to be like that, I want to manage fit them but in a way where the height and width are still good. So if you could please advise.

Comment: @karlkoeller, thanks for your comment. I changed the `t` into `p` but nothing changed.

Comment: You have to scale your figures then (`\includegraphics[scale=0.9]` for example)

Comment: @shepherd Of course they shrink. Or do they get distorted? Your `[width=\linewidth]` shrinks them as well. How do you want to get 5 big pictures on one small page without scaling them? (don't use `newline`, just leave an empty line)

Comment: @karlkoeller Thanks this solved the problem, so if you can post it as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: thanks @LaRiFaRi I removed the `newline` as you suggested and it looks beautiful now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the height of the images is too much. So you have to reduce their height, for example scaling the images with something like

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.9]{animation1}
```

Adjust the scaling factor to your needs.

I'd also suggest to use `p` as a floating specifier so to have your big figure in a page of floats.

An example fith fake images

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\label{animation1}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\label{animation2}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\label{animation3}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\label{animation4}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image}\label{animation5}}
\caption {animation}
\label{animation}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]